# Memory Setting for OC4J in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, memory, oc4j

I've looked on the web for a while and can't seem to find the setting to increase the memory allocated to OC4J when launching from Eclipse.  Does anyone know where the setting is?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add memory setting in the OC4J_JVM_ARGS environment variable. For example you could have something like:

```
OC4J_JVM_ARGS=-Xmx512m
```

You could add others if you want:

```
OC4J_JVM_ARGS=-XX:PermSize=256m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -Xms1024m -Xmx2048m
```

Now, I never have run OC4J from Eclipse (only standalone), but you could do the same by selecting your **Server** view, then **Open launch configuration** and in the **Arguments** tab add the values to the **VM arguments** section directly like:

```
-Xmx512m
```

or

```
-XX:PermSize=256m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -Xms1024m -Xmx2048m
```

Comment: Awesome, the VM Arguments text box was exactly what I was looking for.

Thanks!

Comment: For some reason, the VM Arguments are getting reset every time I close the window after setting the VM arguments.  Any ideas?

I change the value from |
-Djava.library.path=C:"/j2sdk1.4.2_15/bin" -jar | to

| -Djava.library.path=C:"/j2sdk1.4.2_15/bin" -Xmx512m -jar | (Or anything else) > Click Apply > Click Close > Immediately go back to the Arguments tab and they're reset to | -Djava.library.path=C:"/j2sdk1.4.2_15/bin" -jar |

Comment: If you click Apply, the values should be preserved; even if you shutdown Eclipse.

Comment: Apply isn't saving them.  Not sure why.